# ePublishing Conference Proceedings

Tags: publishing, ebook

We have an annual conference, and as part of this conference, we have a curated collection of papers published. Circulation is pretty minimal, so we are working on getting out of dead tree land and into e-publishing for a roughly 250-page compilation of essentially academic papers. But we are having a lot of trouble finding an e-publisher that fits our bill. We are looking for someone that:

- Publishes in PDF with some sort of watermark -- it's a pretty finicky crowd, so we don't want to make technology choices, especially since eReaders are still a bit wild and wide open.
- Does not cost a whole lot up front.
- Can handle all aspects of the transaction and e-delivery -- we just want to hand them the file and largely be done with this.

Is there anyone out there that can satisfy these requirements and do it well?

Comment: First: What are you trying to publish? Novels? technical manuals, thesis papers? Second: A publisher shouldn't cost you /anything./

Comment: Thanks Ralph, I edited the post slightly to fix the "what" angle. You'd be suprised how badly associations get screwed over here -- that is basically what I've been arguing, now I'm trying to back it up.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I found to what you're looking for is [Holcombe Publishing](http://www.holcombepublishing.com/authors). They're specialized in publishing academic books.

As far as I can tell, they request you to lend a hand in cover design and proofreading, and that'd be the only action required from you.

The other points you mentioned, that they handle sales and delivery, are covered. And you only need to submit the work for them to check it out.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about watermarking, but for the rest [Lightning Source](http://www.lightningsource.com/default.aspx) or Lulu should fit your needs. However, if by "publishing" you mean "making papers available for free in an online repository" check also [CEUR-WS](http://ftp.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/Publications/CEUR-WS/).